# Understanding the message in the 'python.exe has stopped working' window

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, exception, crash

While running a Python code, I have received the following error message.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My effort:**
There is a [known bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue13081) with the Exception code as Exception Code: c0000005. I do not know if that is related.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 0xC0000005 is an [`NTSTATUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588) code raised as an exception code. The crash is due to an access violation at offset 0x8C41C in the extension module _sapiremote.pyd. If you create a dump file, the developer of this extension module may be able to use it to analyze and fix the bug that's causing the crash, if the bug is even directly related. This could just be a symptom of an unrelated problem.